# Que devuelve el metodo getValueAt(i, 0); si no encuentra mas celdas en un jTable

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy comparando el contenido de las celdas de un `jTable` con un `String` específico, si lo encuentra procede a la acción correspondiente, pero si no lo encuentra, ¿qué devuelve?

```
while(!(TabVentas.getValueAt(i, 0).toString().equals(fila[0]))) {
    i++;
}
```

El `while` se va a repetir hasta que coincidan los dos `String`: `getValueAt(i,0).toString` y `fila[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según veo el código fuente de `javax.swing.JTable`, se encuentra esto:

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    return getModel().getValueAt(convertRowIndexToModel(row),
                                 convertColumnIndexToModel(column));
}
```

El resultado de `JTable#getModel()` devuelve un elemento que pertenece a la interfaz `TableModel`. Este modelo se puede indicar en el constructor de `JTable`, al no indicarse ninguno, se utilizará un valor por defecto. Coloco el código relevante:

```
public JTable() {
    this(null, null, null);
}

public JTable(TableModel dm, TableColumnModel cm, ListSelectionModel sm) {
    //...
    if (dm == null) {
        dm = createDefaultDataModel();
    }
    setModel(dm);
}

//...

protected TableModel createDefaultDataModel() {
    return new DefaultTableModel();
}
```

Por ende, el resultado de `JTable#getValueAt`, asumiendo que no se le asigna manualmente ningún `TableModel`, va a depender de la implementación de `DefaultTableModel#getValueAt`, cuyo código es:

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    Vector rowVector = (Vector)dataVector.elementAt(row);
    return rowVector.elementAt(column);
}
```

Al ver que este modelo se basa en `Vector`es, el resultado de buscar un elemento cuyos índices no estén en la tabla, se obtendrá `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Puedes revisar las fuentes en línea en las siguientes URLs:

- [`javax.swing.JTable`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/JTable.java)
- [`javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.java)

---

Si quieres navegar por todas las filas disponibles en tu `JTable`, lo mejor sería utilizar `TableModel#getRowCount`:

```
TableModel tm = TabVentas.getModel();
for (int i = 0; i < tm.getRowCount(); i++) {
    //hacer algo con este valor...
    TabVentas.getValueAt(i, 0);
}
```

Comment: Como tendria que hacer para que cuando me salga esa Exception añadir una fila mas a mi jTable

Comment: Cualquier manejo de excepciones se realiza en el segmento `catch`. Allí puedes agregar algo como `try { /* ... */ } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) { /* agregar fila a la tabla */ }`.