# No me muesta nada la hora de consultar la información en la interfaz de Java

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing

Les explico, estoy haciendo un programa de guardar la información de un contacto con `Mysql` y estoy poniendo un `filtro` de búsqueda en la interfaz de `Netbeans`, hace la busqueda pero a la hora de seleccionar a una persona en la tabla no me muestra nada y me da este error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Aquí les dejo el código:

```
public class datos extends javax.swing.JFrame { <- Error

/**
 * Creates new form Datos
 */
String filtro="id";
DefaultTableModel model;

@Override
public Image getIconImage(){
  Image retValue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
  getImage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("imagenes/agregar-usuario.png"));
  return retValue;

}

public datos() {
    initComponents();
    tablaDatos("");
}
void tablaDatos(String Valor){
Connection conectar = null;

 try{

     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     conectar = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/proyecto", "root", "");


 }  catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

  if(combo.getSelectedItem()== "id"){
 filtro= "id";

 }


 if(combo.getSelectedItem()== "nombre"){
 filtro= "Nombre";

 }
 if(combo.getSelectedItem()== "apellido"){
 filtro= "Apellido";

 }


 if(combo.getSelectedItem()== "compañia"){
 filtro= "Compañia";

 }
 String sql="SELECT * FROM datos WHERE "+filtro+" LIKE '%"+Valor+"%'";

    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
     modelo.addColumn("ID");
    modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
      modelo.addColumn("Apellido");
        modelo.addColumn("Email");
          modelo.addColumn("Telefono");
            modelo.addColumn("Compañia");
              modelo.addColumn("Posicion");
                modelo.addColumn("Nota");

                jTable1.setModel(modelo);
                String []datos= new String [8];
                try{
                Statement st=conectar.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
                while(rs.next()){
                datos[0]=rs.getString(1);
                datos[1]=rs.getString(2);
                datos[2]=rs.getString(3);
                datos[3]=rs.getString(4);
                datos[4]=rs.getString(5);
                datos[5]=rs.getString(6);
                datos[6]=rs.getString(7);
                datos[7]=rs.getString(8);

                modelo.addRow(datos);
                }
                jTable1.setModel(modelo);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}




    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 Connection conectar = null;

 try{

     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     conectar = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/proyecto", "root", "");


 }  catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
 try{
 String sql= "UPDATE datos SET id=?," +"Nombre=?,"
         + "Apellido=?,"
         + "Email=?,"
         +"Telefono=?,"
         +"Compañia=?,"
         +"Posicion=?,"
         +"Foto=?,"
         +"Nota=?,"
         +"Ruta=?" 
         +"WHERE id='"+jTextField1.getText()+"'";

 PreparedStatement pst= conectar.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());
        pst.setString(4, jTextField4.getText());
        pst.setString(5, jTextField5.getText());
        pst.setString(6, jTextField6.getText());
        pst.setString(7, jTextField7.getText());
       pst.setString(8, jTextField8.getText());
        FileInputStream Archivofoto = new FileInputStream(jTextField10.getText());
        pst.setBinaryStream(10, Archivofoto);
        pst.setString(9, jTextField10.getText());
        int n = pst.executeUpdate();
        if (n > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se modificaron los datos de manera correcta :D");
            tablaDatos("");

        } else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrio un error, no se pudo modificar los datos :c");

        }
 }  catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    try {
        Connection conectar = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conectar = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/proyecto", "root", "");

        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String insertar = "INSERT INTO datos( id, Nombre, Apellido,Email, Telefono, Compañia, Posicion, Nota, Foto, Ruta)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst = conectar.prepareStatement(insertar);
        pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());
        pst.setString(4, jTextField4.getText());
        pst.setString(5, jTextField5.getText());
        pst.setString(6, jTextField6.getText());
        pst.setString(7, jTextField7.getText());
        pst.setString(8, jTextField8.getText());
        FileInputStream ArchivosFoto;
        FileInputStream Archivofoto = new FileInputStream(jTextField10.getText());
        pst.setBinaryStream(9, Archivofoto);
        pst.setString(10, jTextField10.getText());
        int i = pst.executeUpdate();
        if (i > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha guardadado correctamente :D");
             tablaDatos("");
        } 
        else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrio un error, no se pudo guardar :c");

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            pst.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}                                        

private void jLabel10MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    JFileChooser archivo = new JFileChooser();
    int ventana = archivo.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (ventana == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = archivo.getSelectedFile();
        jTextField10.setText(String.valueOf(file));
        Image foto = getToolkit().getImage(jTextField10.getText());
        jLabel10.setIcon(new ImageIcon(foto));

    }
}                                     

private void jTextField5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
int fx=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"¿Esta realmente seguro de eliminar este registro?"+jTextField1.getText()+"?");
if(fx==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
    Connection conectar = null;

 try{

     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     conectar = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/proyecto", "root", "");


 }  catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

 try{
 Statement s=conectar.createStatement();
 int i=s.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM datos WHERE id='"+jTextField1.getText()+"'");
 if(i==1){
  jTextField1.setText("");
    jTextField2.setText("");
    jTextField3.setText("");
    jTextField4.setText("");
    jTextField5.setText("");
    jTextField6.setText("");
    jTextField7.setText("");
    jTextField8.setText("");
  jLabel10.setIcon(null);
  jTextField10.setText("");
  if (i > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se elimino el registro de forma exitosa :D");
            tablaDatos("");
        } else {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrio un error, no se pudo eliminar el registro :(");

        }
 }
 }  catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}                                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jTextField1.setText("");
    jTextField2.setText("");
    jTextField3.setText("");
    jTextField4.setText("");
    jTextField5.setText("");
    jTextField6.setText("");
    jTextField7.setText("");
  jTextField8.setText("");
  jLabel10.setIcon(null);
  jTextField10.setText("");

}                                        



private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
  int row=jTable1.getSelectedRow();
  String id= 
   Error ->String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0)); <- ERROR
  if(row >= 0){
  jTextField1.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
  jTextField2.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
   jTextField3.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
   jTextField6.setText(jTable1.getValueAt(row, 3).toString()); 

   Connection conectar=null;
   try{
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");   
   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/proyecto", "root", "");   

   }  catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
   try{
    Statement s=conectar.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT Nombre,Apellido,Email,Telefono,Compañia,Posicion,Foto,Nota,Ruta  FROM datos WHERE id='"+id+"'");
    Image i=null;
    Blob blob=rs.getBlob("Foto");
    i=javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream());
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(i); 
    jLabel10.setIcon(image);
    jTextField10.setText(rs.getString(3));


   }  catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }



  }else{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se selecciono fila");    
  }
}                                          


public static void main(String args[]) {

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(datos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: ya comprobaste que si la variable `id` tiene contenido ? y para optimizar en que linea sale ese error ?

Comment: Son muchos errores, editare el post para extender el problema. Son muchos errores así: at datos.jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(datos.java:609).

Comment: si, pero ahi te dice la linea en la que laza la excepcion, pero aqui no podemos ver la linea y seria mas facil, ya que no tenemos en cuneta que mas viene detras

Comment: Ah, disculpa. Voy a poner todo el código para que se aprecie mejor.

Comment: Bro...no me referia a eso, me referia que desmenuces el codigo e indiques donde es el error que te salta, ya que si separas lo que te va bien de los que va mal es mas facil depurar los errores

Comment: Listo, marque con un "Error->" las 2 lineas donde me salta el error. Es probable que no sea así pero es que no tengo mucha experiencia.

Comment: no bro, ese es la clase donde proviene el error, luego quizas te marque en donde se invoque(quizas un metodo) y luego te marca la linea que genera el null

Comment: Me dice que el error se encuentra aquí: String id= String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0));

Comment: eso es lo que te pregunte al comienzo bro, el id esta llegando vacio entonces no lo puedes capturar

Comment: Pero no se porque llega vacío si esta todo especificado...

Comment: Si me puedes ayudar en eso te agradecería :c

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Answer (score 0):

Mira prueba con esto...

```
String id= String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString())
```

Mira este enlace, es casi muy similar a lo que necesitas validar, la captura de la fila.

[Informacion sobre capturar posible NULL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5360/que-devuelve-el-metodo-getvalueati-0-si-no-encuentra-mas-celdas-en-un-jtable)

espero te sirva y la marques xD... ReNiceCode...